# Typescript should I always export my Interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

I have one case that i have never seen before, usually when i create a typescript interface I export it, in order to import it in another file, but right now i have case where my other file recognize the interface even if it is not imported specially IBuffer

```
import {
  IObjectStorageClient,
  IUploadObjectResult,
  IDeleteObjectResult,
  IDeleteObjectOptions,
  IDownloadObjectOptions,
  IDownloadObjectResult
} from    "personnalLib"
import * as _request from 'superagent';
import {  IInfraStorageConfig } from "../../config/configs";

    class StorageService implements IStorageService{
      public infraStorageConf : IInfraStorageConfig;
      public client: IObjectStorageClient;

        public async saveBuffers(bufferToSave:IBuffer):Promise<any> {

            //  bufferTosave.infraKeyValue =bufferTosave.infraKeyValue ? bufferTosave.infraKeyValue : [] as any

             const access_token= (await this.generateStorageToken()).access_token;
                  try{

                    const storageResponse = await this.client.uploadObject({
                        data: Buffer.from(bufferToSave.data!),
                        contentType: bufferToSave!.contentType!,
                        objectName: bufferToSave.fileName!,
                        ttl: bufferToSave.ttl?bufferToSave.ttl:0, // ~1 year
                        accessToken:access_token
                      }).catch((err: any) =>{
                          throw err
                      })


                        return {
                          key:storageResponse.objectId,
                          value:storageResponse.metadata
                        };
                      }catch(err){
                        throw err
                      }
        }
```

So My question is ? Is it a new feature ? because some of my collegue cannot compile this kind of code and i can, i have in type 2.9.2 in workspeace and VSCode is in 3.7,

here is my compiler option :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
 }
```

and they extend this compiler options from a lib :

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig-required.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "newLine": "LF",
    "charset": "utf8",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "plugins": [{
      "name": "tslint-language-service"
    }]
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "temp", "node_modules", "output", "log", "test-data", "generated", ".*"]
}
```

here is the ts-config-required.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  }
```

Comment: Well, apparently if you want anyone else to be able to use your code, yes, you should export your interface :).

Comment: then it mean it's not a must for my internal interface ?